# Segfault when attempting to de-reference iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, std

I'm trying to get minmax elements from a vector. Below is an overly simplified snippet of my code:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  vec.push_back(i);
}
auto minmax = std::minmax(vec.begin(), vec.end());
int min_value = *minmax.first;
```

I get a segfault when I try to de-reference the iterator in the last statement. I don't understand why.

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to de-reference it? I'd double check [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax). You may be confusing this with [`std::mixmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element).

Comment: Basically you are trying to get and int value at some memory location address and as address you are using the min value in your vector.. that sounds weird to me.

Comment: Do you realize this is finding the smallest and largest of the two *iterators* ? Ie. not the values they point to ?

Comment: another reason to avoid using `auto`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is not as obvious as it could be. As others have already suggested, you are using the wrong algorithm, or using the algorithm in a wrong way. When you want to work with iterators and pass in a range, use this:

```
auto minmax = std::minmax_element(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend());
int min_value = *minmax.first;
```

If you instead want to use `std::minmax`, you need to either pass two arguments of the type that you *intend to compare*, or a `std::initializer_list`:

```
auto minmax1 = std::minmax_element(42, 43);
auto minmax2 = std::minmax_element({42, 43, 50, 49, 40});

int min_value = minmax1.first;
```

In the second example, it's not iterators that are returned, but `const`-qualified references or values (when an initializer list has been passed).

**Why did you make that mistake?** It turns out that passing iterators to `std::minmax` happily compiles because `std::minmax` is a function template that compares any types you give it. In this case, `vec.begin()` and `vec.end()` are random access iterators, and they can be compared by `operator <`. A random access iterator to the beginning of a sequence will always compare less to one that points to the end, so the min value you get back is in fact a pair of `const` references to `vec.begin()` and `vec.end()` because `vec.begin() < vec.end()` (no intermediate values were considered), but as they aren't alive anymore after the function invocation, using them (e.g. dereferencing them) is UB (additional note: you could theoretically work around that by `int min_value = *std::minmax(vec.begin(), vec.end()).first;`, which dereferences the returned interator while it isn't dangling, but this is just fixing the UB part and does not what you want, i.e., it still compares the two iterators, not elements in the range).

Note that when you try to compile this example with a `std::list<int>` instead of a `std::vector`, it won't compile because `std::list` iterators aren't random access and can't be compared by `operator <`.

Sometimes, it seems, the power of random access can get you into trouble :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to dereference the pair to get the value.
[`std::minmax`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax) returns a reference to the min and max or returns by value.

If you meant to get an iterator to the element then you have to use [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element)
instead.

**Edit**

What you are doing in your code is finding min and max of two iterators then you need to dereference to get the values.  [live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GZ5W12hWCTlRwjNh)

Answer (score 2):

Your program crashes because `minmax` takes iterators by calling `begin`/`end` and these iterators are destroyed when the full expresssion ends:

```
auto minmax = std::minmax(vec.begin(), vec.end()); // pass iterators as temporary [1]
int min_value = *minmax.first; // here, you have dangling references to iterators
```

`minmax` returns pair of references to iterators, which were destroyed.

In line [1] `begin`/`end` returns iterators by value, so they are bound to `const T&` as param of `minmax` but their lifetime end up when the line [1] was performed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably interpret the meaning of `std::minmax` wrong: `std::minmax` either takes *two arguments* (leading to comparing just these two), or *one argument*  of type `initializer_list` (searching for min max then therein).

If you pass two iterators, as you do with `std::minmax(vec.begin(),vec.end())`, then `minmax` will *not* iterate from begin to end, but it will compare the iterators `begin()` and `end()`; the result will be a pair where one of the two elements contains iterator `vec.end()`, and the other contains iterator `vec.begin()`.

So for getting values, you actually have to dereference `minmax.first`, since it contains an iterator. But as either `minmax.first` or ``minmax.second`will contain`vec.end()`, you actually dereference`vec.end()`, which is undefined behaviour.

For getting the smallest/largest element in a range, write...

```
int smallest_element = *min_element(vec.begin(),vec.end());
```